# Apache CXF - How to know while sending which response "Broken pipe" is occuring

Tags: cxf

I see lots of exceptions[ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe] in
my catalina log while trying to send the response back but i am not able to tie this exception 
to a particular request with a particular Inbound Message ID, Is there any way by which i can know, while sending
which  response this exception is occuring in cxf ?

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling SOAP logging. If you enable SOAP logging as follows, you will see SOAP requests and/or responses including HTTP headers. CXF also assigns a message ID for each request/response.

```
@WebService
@org.apache.cxf.annotations.Logging
public interface AssetServices {
....
}
```